# how to attribute code from a website?

Tags: html, css, web

I found a website useful for designing my own site and took parts of the code to modify it for my personal use.I have added my content but parts of the html and css are from this original website.
do I attribute the work by providing a link to the original developer's page ? I've done so under the footer but was wondering if more is required to give proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legally? It depends entirely on the license that the original author has decided to publish their work under. There are a multitude of open source licenses each with slightly different attribution and reuse requirements (even [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1))

Morally? That's entirely up to you. If you're using a substantial amount of code, a callout on the page may be appropriate. Maybe just a comment will do. Or maybe no attribution at all if the license (and your conscience) allows it.

Answer (score 3):

You do so in whatever manner the license they gave you to use their code says you should, and you should ask the copyright holder if it is unclear.